# Create copy of column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a copy of column in a table. Why

```
df.col_new = df.col
```

does not work but

```
df['col_new'] = df['col']
```

does?

Comment: [From the docs on attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access) "be careful; if you try to use attribute access to create a new column, it creates a new attribute rather than a new column."

Comment: The dot notation for column access has its limits.  Alway use df['colname'].  A longtime ago, I complete stopped using df.colname in favor of `df['colname']`.